# Is There any angular module destroyed event like componet ngDestroy

Tags: angular

Is there any event there to listening to the module destroy? At that event, I want to clear my local storage

Comment: no, ngmodules are never destroyed. clear local storage from a component ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question it's important to understand the difference between `module` and `component`.

In general and oversimplified terms:

1. **Module** is used to group multiple components together
2. **Component** is where all the logic happens and you actually build your app

Users that browse your app don't end up on modules, but on a component **that belongs to a module**.

Therefor you can hook to a place where a component destroys, but not a module.

---

### **Now, how can you hook to when a module gets destroyed?**

If you want to have some kind of logic and make sure that it happens only when a module gets destroyed, you can have a module that has a component which optionally can have child components, then hook to where that first container component gets destroyed, and you can be sure that at the point this happens are navigating to a different module. (because they are all in the same module and navigating in and out of inner components won't trigger the `OnDestroy` lifecycle function.

Here's an example taken from the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router):

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'first-component',
    component: FirstComponent, // this is the component with the <router-outlet> in the template
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child-a', // child route path
        component: ChildAComponent, // child route component that the router renders
      },
      {
        path: 'child-b',
        component: ChildBComponent, // another child route component that the router renders
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Then you can hook with the `OnDestroy` lifecycle. Here's an example taken from the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy):

```js
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // ...
  }
}
```